# Darkstat unable to show recent statistics

Tags: linux, debian

We have a debian machine running with firewall / gateway. We have deployed darkstat on it.

When we installed darkstat it was showing statistics properly. After few days it stopped showing recent statistics. The data was getting appended to existing one. Please anyone tell me what could be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rotating your logfiles with logrotate daily.